# Is it possible to make array of pairs

Tags: c++, vector, std-pair

I am new to c++ so I want to ask is it possible to make an array of pair in c++ just like we create a vector of pair.

```
int n;
 cin>>n;
 array < pair <int,int> >v[n];
```

I am trying to make array like this but not getting positive results.

Comment: `std::array` requires the second template parameter - the size of the array. Which has to be known and fixed at compile time.

Comment: As size is runtime value, you cannot use it for `std::array` or C-array.

Comment: Same way you make any other array: `type name[size]`. You want to make an array named array, right? What you're doing here is also called a variable-length array and isn't legal C++. Some compilers allow it. You should avoid it when possible, for example using a `std::vector` of `pair<int, int>`s.

Comment: @IgorTandetnik can you show me how?

Comment: Can who show you how to do what? Use `@` to respond to specific people.

Comment: `std::vector<std::pair<int, int>> v(n);`?

Comment: @Jarod42 thanks I got it

Comment: `std::array<std::pair<int, int>, 42> v;`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It looks like you are trying to dynamically allocate an array of `pair<int,int>`s'. Prefer std::vector for such a task:

```
#include<vector>

int n;

cin>>n;

std::vector<pair<int,int>> v(n);
```

As to your original question, you can create arrays of `pair<int,int>`s', either C-style arrays or std::arrays, however, you will need to know the size at compile-time:

```
int n;

cin >> n;


//C-style arrays
pair<int,int> a[n]; //this may work on some compilers, but is non-standard behaviour

//std::arrays
#include<array>

std::array<pair<int,int>,n> a; //this will not compile at all, "n" must be known at compile-time
```

Comment: so you are trying to say that if I take input of size from user at run-time than I would not be able to make array of pairs.

Comment: @cgDude yes, thats correct. You could dynamically allocate the memory, however you would have to remember to free the memory after you're done. In this scenario, it is best practice to use a std::vector.

Answer (score 0):

you can with std::pair
but if you want a c style way and not depend on std you can create a struct

```
struct MyStruct
{
    int val1;
    int val2;
    char* description;
};

int main()
{
    MyStruct str[100];

}
```

or for modern using std::vector and std::pair way you can find example on other answer

you also can use std::tuple instead of std::pair for more than two values

std::map may be useful based on your usage too